# DateOffset Panda substraction

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame

```
[in] MyDates
[out]  
2017-04-04        -5.0
2017-04-03        -5.0
2017-03-31        -4.0
2017-03-30        -6.0
2017-03-29        -5.0
2017-03-28        -5.0
```

Each numbers correspond of how much day I should add or remove from the corresponding date. I want to crate a new column with the index date minus the number of days which are in the column one. I know I can do it with DateOffset but I can't figure out how...

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a Series or a df?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert column to [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html) or [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and `add` (`+`) or substract `(-)` values:

```
df['new'] = df.index - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['col'], unit='d')
print (df)
            col        new
2017-04-04 -5.0 2017-04-09
2017-04-03 -5.0 2017-04-08
2017-03-31 -4.0 2017-04-04
2017-03-30 -6.0 2017-04-05
2017-03-29 -5.0 2017-04-03
2017-03-28 -5.0 2017-04-02
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df['col'], unit='d')
print (df)
            col        new
2017-04-04 -5.0 2017-03-30
2017-04-03 -5.0 2017-03-29
2017-03-31 -4.0 2017-03-27
2017-03-30 -6.0 2017-03-24
2017-03-29 -5.0 2017-03-24
2017-03-28 -5.0 2017-03-23
```

If `Series` as `input` add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = s.to_frame('date')
df['new'] = df.index - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['date'], unit='d')
print (df)
            date        new
2017-04-04  -5.0 2017-04-09
2017-04-03  -5.0 2017-04-08
2017-03-31  -4.0 2017-04-04
2017-03-30  -6.0 2017-04-05
2017-03-29  -5.0 2017-04-03
2017-03-28  -5.0 2017-04-02
```

Comment: I am not sure, so I will add both solutions.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you want to construct a `TimedeltaIndex` and add this:

```
In [173]:    
df.index + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['days'], unit='d')

Out[173]:
DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-30', '2017-03-29', '2017-03-27', '2017-03-24',
               '2017-03-24', '2017-03-23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If it's a column you just do `df['Dates'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['days'], unit='d')`

```
In [176]:
df['offset_date'] = df['Dates'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['days'], unit='d')
df

Out[176]:
       Dates  days offset_date
0 2017-04-04  -5.0  2017-03-30
1 2017-04-03  -5.0  2017-03-29
2 2017-03-31  -4.0  2017-03-27
3 2017-03-30  -6.0  2017-03-24
4 2017-03-29  -5.0  2017-03-24
5 2017-03-28  -5.0  2017-03-23
```

If it's the index and you want to add as a column it's pretty much the same op:

```
In [180]:    
df['offset_date'] = df.index + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['days'], unit='d')
df

Out[180]:
            days offset_date
Dates                       
2017-04-04  -5.0  2017-03-30
2017-04-03  -5.0  2017-03-29
2017-03-31  -4.0  2017-03-27
2017-03-30  -6.0  2017-03-24
2017-03-29  -5.0  2017-03-24
2017-03-28  -5.0  2017-03-23
```

Comment: Might seem like a random comment, but just wanted a look back with you on the journey to `100K`. I remember seeing you post answers, when I started answering NumPy questions back in the summer of 2015 and we were about at the same rep at around `35-40K`. Somehow our Stackoverflow journeys have been parallel, not just in terms of the rep, but the intentions of improving the SO community through posting answers and keeping it clean with cleansing dup questions and such stuffs in general. So, just wanted to congratulate you on this achievement and the journey thus far :)

Comment: @Divakar thanks.. I've always been impressed at your numpy expertise, I always learn something new. To be honest I've been a bit jaded with SO due to poor questions or the first-answer to questions that are poor/have a dupe/ or constantly needing to mod the answer due to shifting targets. I look forward to your 100K rep goal and will assist in anyway I can

Comment: Yeah, that constant need for modding to close dup ones specially with data based languages/modules/packages has been a problem. Maybe SO would design a better model to close/handle those. Let's hope for the best and enjoy the moment for now :)